# T4MVC and DisplayModeProvider issue with fully qulified views

Tags: t4mvc

I have code that detects the user agent and creates a new display mode (ie. "tablet" and "mobile")

`DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode("mobile")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => GetDeviceType(context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()) == "mobile")
    });`

so when i want to return a view i just have to

`return View("Index")`

and the display mode will append "Index.tablet.cshtml" or "Index.mobile.cshtml" or nothing "Index.cshtml" for the default.

what is great about this is that if the user agent is "mobile" and there is no "Index.mobile.cshtml" file it will default to "Index.cshtml"

this works well but when using a fully qualified view name, as t4mvc does, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"
the display mode logic does not add "tablet" or "mobile".

is there a way to have t4mvc return just "index" and not the fully qualified name?

or do you have another suggestion on how to resolve this issue and still use t4mvc?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just choose `return (MVC.YourController.Views.ViewNames.YourView)`